# Lighthouse CI seemingly not using localStorage token setup by Puppeteer auth script

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, lighthouse

I seem to be having the same problem as the person in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977668/how-to-run-lighthouse-for-the-homepage-after-login-from-puppeteer) question. I've setup a puppeteer script to run as part of my lhci autorun command which looks like this:

```
async function main() {
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({product: "chrome", headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.remoteurl.com/login');

  await page.waitForSelector('.fmt-btn')
  const emailInput = await page.$('input[name="login"]');
  await emailInput.type('username');
  const passwordInput = await page.$('input[type="password"]');
  await passwordInput.type('password');
  const loginButton = await page.$('button[type="submit"]')
  await loginButton.click();

  await delay(5000);

  await page.close();
}

module.exports = main;
```

And my lighthouserc.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const merge = require('deepmerge');

module.exports = merge.all([
  {
    ci: {
      collect: {
        url: ['https://remoteurl.com/page/to/test'],
        puppeteerScript: 'puppeteer-auth.js'
      },
      upload: {
        target: 'filesystem',
        outputDir: '.',
        reportFilenamePattern: 'lighthouse.report.%%EXTENSION%%'
      }
    },
  },
]);
```

When I execute `lhci autorun` I watch an instance of Chrome launch and the credentials I specified in my `puppeteer-auth.js` file be entered, submitted and I see the page I would expect to see upon a successful login.

After 5 seconds, the page closes and LHCI continues itself. It generates 3 separate reports and when I open them they all show the show they are hitting the desired URL but the screenshots show they are testing against the login page.

I think this is due to the fact that the token used for authentication is kept in local storage of a different URL and that maybe they aren't shared?

[image: local storage]

Hopefully this image explains it but I need a token stored in the local storage of one website in order to bypass the login of the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've done a bit more work into it and it seems that the lighthouse headless browser is hitting our login page that displays an error that the browser isn't Chrome. Interestingly this same piece of logic is hit when Puppeteer logs in but this passes.

The logic is

```
var isChrome = (function(){
  var isChromium = window.chrome;
  var winNav = window.navigator;
  var vendorName = winNav.vendor;
  var isOpera = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1;
  var isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
  var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

  return !isIOSChrome && (isChromium !== null && isChromium !== undefined && vendorName === "Google Inc." && isOpera === false && isIEedge === false);
}());
```

Would this cause the LHCI browser to return false?

EDIT 2:
I'm fairly certain it's because lhci and Puppeteer aren't using the same browser. Following an example similar to [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/puppeteer.md#option-1-launch-chrome-with-puppeteer-and-handoff-to-lighthouse) I can watch it log in and produce the results I want. Unfortunately I don't know how to translate this to work in LHCI.